# Maven compile of groovy classes fails in mixed java-groovy app

Tags: java, maven, groovy, intellij-idea

I've got an application with Groovy and Java classes. Compilation under IDEA 11 works **fine**, but when i'm trying to compile with Maven it **fails**.

Project structure: *src/main/groovy* - for groovy classes, *src/main/java* - for java classes. For example, class TemplateWriter tries to use groovy class AbstractTemplate.

```
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\io\TemplateWriter.java:[16,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AbstractTemplate
```

Similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139665/groovy-application-classes-and-java-unit-tests). But nothing helps :(

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>adapter-builder</groupId>
    <artifactId>adapter-builder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.0</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.5</source>
                   <target>1.5</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
               <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.4</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>compile</phase>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>    
</project>
```

The whole output from maven:compile

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java" -Dclassworlds.conf=C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=C:\apache-maven-2.2.1 -Didea.launcher.port=7535 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.0\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --no-plugin-updates --strict-checksums --update-snapshots -f D:\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\pom.xml compile
+ Enabling strict checksum verification on all artifact downloads.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Unnamed - adapter-builder:adapter-builder:jar:1.0
[INFO]    task-segment: [compile]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 37 source files to D:\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[7,0] package com.itransition.smev.builder.templates does not exist
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\io\TemplateWriter.java:[3,45] package com.itransition.smev.builder.templates does not exist
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\io\TemplateWriter.java:[16,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AbstractTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.io.TemplateWriter
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[23,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VarTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[23,35] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VarTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[38,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[38,45] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[46,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[46,52] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[57,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[57,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[68,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiGetSignRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[68,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiGetSignRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[79,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsFoivRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[79,45] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsFoivRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[89,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[89,42] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[99,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[ERROR] \Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[99,43] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
[INFO] 19 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[7,0] package com.itransition.smev.builder.templates does not exist
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\io\TemplateWriter.java:[3,45] package com.itransition.smev.builder.templates does not exist
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\io\TemplateWriter.java:[16,29] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class AbstractTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.io.TemplateWriter
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[23,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VarTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[23,35] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class VarTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[38,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[38,45] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[46,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[46,52] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[57,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[57,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiSetDocResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[68,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiGetSignRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[68,53] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsXwikiGetSignRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[79,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsFoivRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[79,45] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WsFoivRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[89,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[89,42] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplRequestTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[99,8] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator
\Projects\SMEV\_Generator\adapter-builder\src\main\java\com\itransition\smev\builder\core\AdapterFileGenerator.java:[99,43] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TplResponseTemplate
location: class com.itransition.smev.builder.core.AdapterFileGenerator

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Dec 07 04:57:10 VET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/33M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is this class AbstractTemplate in the project or is it in an external project

Comment: It is one project, two source folders.

Comment: I think that wrong classpath is being built when groovy sources are being compiled. This plugin (gmaven) has tricky classpath issues (I know this since we're using it in our project). Can you post classpath to the question? Also, try to set `<providerSelection>` option to 2.0 in plugin configuration.

Comment: *Can you post classpath to the question* -What do you mean?

Comment: You execute with `-X` and check classpath when groovy code is being compiled.